# linking to comment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are Posts, Comments and Reports. Report belongs to a Comment(which belongs to a Post). I want to create a link to a comment(together to a post it belongs to) on Report's show page.

It should look something like this

> .../posts/2/comments/4

I have this on report's show page, which gives me ID for a comment.

```
<%= @report.comment.id %>
```

How do I link to a Comment's show page on Report's show page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have nested routes as `comments` within `posts`, for e.g.:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Then you would have path as `post_comment_path` routing to `/posts/:post_id/comments/:id`.

In that case, you can have a link to a Comment's show page on Report's show page as below:

```
<%= link_to "Comment's Show Page" , post_comment_path(post_id: @report.comment.post.id, id: @report.comment.id) %>
```